# how to send HTTP posts using okhttp android

Tags: php, android, mysql, post, okhttp

Hi I have problem with okhttp
I want to send Http posts to php script that post will sent to mysql database

this my MainActivity Code

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helousername);
        String myusername = username.getText().toString();

    }

    private void registerusername(String myusername) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("username",myusername)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://192.168.10.10/mynoti/register.php")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this my php code register.php

```
 <?php 
    if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
           $user_acc=$_POST['username'];
           $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","usersaccount") or die("Error connecting");
           $q="INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('1','test@email.com','$user_acc')";

      mysqli_query($conn,$q) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
      mysqli_close($conn);
    }
 ?>
```

the code of main_activity.xml is simple

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="helo"
    android:id="@+id/helousername"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="153dp" />
```

every thinks are fine no error no nothing
but when I open the app it's not send HTTP post to the server

help me please
thank you.

Comment: Where are you calling this "registerusername" function.. ?

Comment: when i call registerusername(myusername) in onCreate the app crash

Comment: Please post the error log.

Comment: but there is no error ! where i can found the errors ?

Comment: http://www.chengxuyuans.com/uploads/allimg/141214/1I5334612-0.png